# Saving data to disk on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults

My application got rejected for following reason:

```
App Review
1.0 Binary Rejected August 5, 2015
2.23 Details On launch and content download, your app stores 9.51 MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage
```

As much as I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) it's because I save too much on `NSUserDefaults`(I don't save anywhere else).

So here's my question: Is there a quick, easy way to save data locally(similiar to `NSUserDefaults` but not end up saving on "user's iCloud", instead of using `CoreData`?

Comment: yes, that is a quite hug amount of information to save into `NSUserDefaults`, what about _serializing_ your data into to the `Documents` folder instead? that would be a quite obvious choice in your case... that can be your ultimate guidance for achieving that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.
You can store your data using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.
`NSKeyedArchiver` is used to save your data. An example:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:counters toFile:filePath];
```

Extension of the `filePath` should be `.plist`; `counters` in this case is an array.

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` is used to load your data. An example:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    counters = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
}
```

If you want to store your custom class, you need to implement `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: Ok great, now can I be using something like:   
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
let fileName = "\(documentsDirectory)/file1"

for "`fileName`"?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. If not, try to put `.plist` at the end of the path.

Comment: Ok, generally my app won't get rejected if I save that much like that to the documents directory?

Comment: No, it won't. It's actually a small amount of data.